# What's the lowest atmospheric pressure a tardigrade can remain active in?

Tags: zoology, metabolism, ecology, environment

I'm not asking what atmospheric pressures they can *survive* (we now they can survive the vacuum of space) I'm wondering at what point a deficit of atmospheric pressure would cause them to enter one of their various states of metabolic suspension.